# NebulaGraph Database: LpaExample algorithm does not finish execution.roblem with the algorithm parameters

Tags: nebula-graph

When using NebulaGraph Database and running an `LpaExample` algorithm — it does not finish execution. Could there be a problem with the algorithm parameters?

The execution of the code takes too long, and it always seems to be unfinished. If `Int.MaxValue` is set to a specific value, e.g. `3` or `5`, the execution will be completed.

[image]

How large `LPAConfig()` parameter can still be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The label propagation algorithm, not like some of the other algorithms, won't converge itself.

We should configure the max iteration to explicitly let it stop after it's reached.

In your case(data volume), it looks like `maxValue` is way too large to have the execution done in a reasonable time.